# Angularjs ui-bootstrap datepicker is not working in my application

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is code which I am to trying to run in my application. Even I have the same versions of js and css. here is the plunker link. [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jPIqRulZFkOki0sFx1v6?p=preview) of original code, here.

```
 //html code
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Popup</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
//Js code
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };
};
```

This code I have applied exactly same in my controller, I have included dependency modules also, I have same versions as in plunker. but is not working in my application. I am struggling from last 2 days. Please somebody let me know the reason.
Here is my html

```
<h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" />hi{{dt}}
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="opencal($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

....//my ctrl is home ctrl here so this code wrapped in homectl.
```

Here is my js code

```
 //app code.
    var app1 = angular.module("HomeApp",['uiSlider','ui.bootstrap']);
    //this where i defined dependency.
        app1.controller('HomeCtrl', function( $scope,$http,$q,$location,$window,$routeParams,$modal, $log) {
    //here is my datepicker code.
          $scope.opencal = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            $scope.opened = true;
          };
    ...//my rest code goes below
```

Queries I have is

- **I cant see date when I select date from calendar.(in {{dt}}).**
- **I need to pass selected date to my home controller.**

Comment: please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/amITG7wP6ovuC86lMFb5?p=preview it's looks like you missed ngRoute

Comment: You may be running into the Prototypal inheritance gotcha as described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).  It's considered best practice not to bind directly to primitives.  I've seen some patterns where this is used: $scope.vm = $scope;  Then bind to vm.property.

Comment: @sylwester I dont think old version of angular needs ng-route. please edit that plunker with ng-route and comment where you include ng-route.

Comment: @RobJ I have seen thank you for the link but it does not worked even after assigning to property. please edit in plunker and provide me link.

Comment: Guys I have angular v1.1.5, So I tried to moving newest version I added ngRoute dependancy also included into js files, added link to my application, but still I am getting empty view. What are the things I missed while updating from 1.1.5 to newset ng 1.3.12?
Do you thing because of old version I am not getting datepicker ?

Comment: or please suggest me how can I work this in angular 1.1.5.

Comment: Got guys thanks very much 
Actually it was version problem and I used compartable version (0.6.0)of ui-bootstrap for angular 1.1.5.

Comment: But not able to change the format of ng-modal in controller please help me guys.... I want to change ng-modal format to 'yyyy-DD-mm'. I have tried applying filter to {{dt|date:'yyyy-DD-mm'}} but this doesnt changes the value of ng-modal which is dt.